# Laravel 10: How to write HasOne relationship that contains "where()" with dynamic value?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `HasOne` relationship on my `ExtraField` model:

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function fieldValue(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(ExtraFieldValue::class, 'extra_field_id')
        ->withDefault([
            'value' => null,
        ]);
}
```

The above works, however I have to specify that only Extra Field Values that belong to a specific `owner_model_id` are picked.

The following works when I call my `ExtraField::with('fieldValue')` but I cannot hardcode `2` or any other value.

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function fieldValue(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(ExtraFieldValue::class, 'extra_field_id')
        ->where('owner_model_id', '=', 2) // this works but I cannot hardcode "2"
        ->withDefault([
            'value' => null,
        ]);
}
```

How can I narrow down by `owner_model_id` column in a "dynamic" way? I know that I cannot inject any value into relationship method.

**Edit:**

The `owner_model_id` is a column on `extra_field_values` table.

[image]

Comment: Where do you derive this value `owner_model_id` from?

Comment: The `owner_model_id` is a column on `extra_field_values` table. I have updated the question @Ohgodwhy.

Comment: Sorry, more specifically, when you want to query this, where would you derive this value from? `auth()->user()->getKey()` for example?

Comment: It is indeed a PK from another model. I have a very simple repository method where I'm allowed to inject any Eloquent `Model $model` and that hardcoded `2` comes from my injected model's `$model->getKey()`.

Comment: if this relation is on `$model` then you can use `$this->getKey()` in the relation method, otherwise I would say you would need to make a query scope (or do the where manually). query scopes can have default values look at `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope::class`. To eager load with the scope `ExtraField::with(['fieldValue' => fn (\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation $query) => $query->scope()])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereRelation()` for this where you call the query:

```
Model::whereRelation('relation','coulmn_name','value')->get()
```

Comment: You clearly don't understand what the question is about.